# Loop inside function

Tags: javascript

I try to create an function using this scenario

```
var obj = new String('world');

obj.length;

var i = 0;

for( i= 0;i<obj.length; i++) {
    document.write(obj[i] + " is letter " + i );
    document.write("<br />");
}
```

What I create 'till this moment it is this function

```
function obj(x) {

    var y = x;
    var doj = new String(y);

    for (var i= 0;  i<doj.length; i++) {
        return document.write(doj[i] + " is letter " + i );
        document.write("<br />")
    }

}

obj("coguuu");
```

Comment: I tried to create a function that will write c is 0 o is letter 1 but i'm stack to first letter

Comment: Any reason you do `new String('world');` instead of just `'world'`?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you returned the function in the first step of the loop. Remove that `return`.

Comment: post (doj[i] + " is letter " + i );
    post();
    }
    return doj;
    }

    obj("dog");